# Display glitch. Extra space after apostrophe when creating word documents VBA

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I have this VBA code that takes two documents (one original document and one revision document with blue text to be added) and creates a third document with the revisions.It mostly works, but when the third copy is created, there is extra space after apostrophes. It isn't actually an extra space though. Upon selecting the "Hidden Formatting" button in Word, it shows that there isn't actually a space at all. The character is just being displayed on the monitor incorrectly. I have tried a few things such as changing the font during the file creation and using the REPLACE function to no avail. This is not an isolated incident, [I found this documentation on the problem, unfortunately it does not pertain to VBA](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/why-does-word-2011-add-a-space-when-i-use/7e71bf0d-526f-4cfd-8764-4f44b327e18e). Looking for some ideas on how to fix the problem.

```
Sub WordReplaceSentence()

MsgBox "Welcome to the word document automatic modifier", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

MsgBox "Please open the revision file", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

    Dim strfilename1 As String
    Dim fd1 As Office.FileDialog

   ''''''Browsing/Opening the change request'''''''

    Set fd1 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd1

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Open the modified word document."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Word 2010", "*.docx"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
        strfilename1 = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
      Else
      Exit Sub
      End If
   End With



MsgBox "Open the orginal document", vbInformation + vbOKOnly


Dim strfilename2 As String

    Dim fd2 As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd2

      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the original file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "Word 2010", "*.docx"
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
        strfilename2 = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
      Else
      Exit Sub
      End If
   End With


MsgBox "Please enter the file name with which you want to store the new updated file", vbInformation + vbOKOnly


''''''''''''''''''Asking user to input name to the new revised document'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim strfilename3 As String

    Dim fd3 As Office.FileDialog

    Set fd3 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

   With fd3
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the name to be given to the new file."
      If .Show = True Then
        strfilename3 = .SelectedItems(1) 'replace txtFileName with your textbox
      Else
      Exit Sub
      End If
   End With



    FileCopy strfilename2, strfilename3

    Set objWordChange = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objWordorig = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    objWordChange.Visible = False
    objWordorig.Visible = False

    Set objDocChange = objWordChange.Documents.Open(strfilename1)
    Set objSelectionChange = objWordChange.Selection
    Set objDocOrig = objWordorig.Documents.Open(strfilename3)
    Set objSelectionOrig = objWordorig.Selection

    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long


    'We'll store the sentences here
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set rSearch = objDocChange.Range
    With rSearch
        .Find.Forward = True
        .Find.Format = True
        .Find.Font.Color = wdColorBlue
        .Find.Execute

        Do While .Find.Found
            'key = revised sentence, item = original sentence
            'if the revised sentence already exists in the dictionary, replace the found word in the entry
            If dict.Exists(.Sentences(1).Text) Then
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), Space(2), Space(1))
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), " ,", ",")
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), " .", ".")
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), " '", "'")
                 For Each Key In dict
                        Debug.Print "KEY: " & Key
                        Debug.Print "Item: " & Item
                    Next

            Else
            'if the revised sentence isn't in the dict, then this is the first found word, so add it and replace the word
                dict.Add .Sentences(1).Text, Replace$(Replace$(.Sentences(1).Text, .Text, vbNullString), Space(2), Space(1))
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), " ,", ",")
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), " .", ".")
                dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text) = Replace$(Replace$(dict.Item(.Sentences(1).Text), .Text, vbNullString), " '", "'")
            End If
            .Find.Execute
        Loop
    End With

    'Loop through all the dictionary entries and find the origial (item) and replace With
    'the revised (key)
    For i = 1 To dict.Count
        Set rSearch = objDocOrig.Range
        With rSearch.Find
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchPhrase = True
            .IgnoreSpace = True
            .IgnorePunct = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = dict.Items(i - 1)
            .Replacement.Text = dict.Keys(i - 1)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

        End With
        With objDocOrig.Range
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        End With
    Next i

objDocChange.Close
objDocOrig.Save
objDocOrig.Close

objWordChange.Quit
objWordorig.Quit

End Sub
```

If you need / want to test my code, you will have to create two word documents. Each document will need a common sentence containing an apostrophe (obviously). The second document would require a few blue words in addition to the original sentence in RGB 0,0,225.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question. I had to disable the "Asian Text Font" in the Font Pane. This can be done by going into the Microsoft Language Register and disabling various languages. [Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/disabling-asian-text-font-in-the-font-pane/2599da8c-fefe-4905-ad24-cae877dbdc69)